# Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice) vs. Array.prototype.slice.call

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am trying to write a static version of slice.

What is the difference between

```
Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice)
```

and

```
Array.prototype.slice.call.
```

If I write:

```
var x = Array.prototype.slice.call; 
x([1,2,3]);
```

I get

```
TypeError: object is not a function.
```

Why is this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript "this" keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Answer (score 1):

The function `Array.prototype.slice.call` is the same exact function as `Function.prototype.call`. It does not know that `Array.prototype.slice` should be `this` unless you call it as a method, like so:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(whatever);
```

or if you use one of a few other ways to tell it what `this` is. When you assign it to `x`, you lose the `this` information.

`Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice)` creates a function that *does* know that `Array.prototype.slice` is `this`. Even if you attach it to a new object and call it as a method of the new object:

```
x = {call: Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice)}
x.call([1, 2, 3])
```

It will behave as though it were called as `Array.prototype.slice.call` instead of `x.call`.

Comment: There is a section in [Javascript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this) that explains this idea, that when you assign a method to a variable you lose the this context. I did not fully digest it, though, so I could not make the connection myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your hint - this is true:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call == (function() {}).call
```

`call` is a member of `Function.prototype` - it expects the `this` argument to point to the function to call. You're passing it nothing, so `this` refers to the `window` object. This will work:

```
x = Array.prototype.slice.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice)
```

But from my first code snippet, `Array.prototype.slice.call` is just `Function.prototype.call`, so:

```
x = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice)
```

In fact, `Function.call == Function.prototype.call`, so you can do

```
x = Function.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice)
```

Comment: He's not passing the array as `this`, he's passing *nothing*.